# How to set group.id for consumer group in kafka data source in Structured Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I want to use Spark Structured Streaming to read from a secure kafka. This means that I will need to force a specific group.id. However, as is stated in the documentation this is not possible.
Still, in the databricks documentation https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/structured-streaming/kafka.html#using-ssl, it says that it is possible. Does this only refer to the azure cluster?

Also, by looking at the documentation of the master branch of the apache/spark repo https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.md, we can understand that such functionality is intended to be added at later spark releases. Do you know of any plans of such a stable release, that is going to allow setting that consumer group.id?

If not, are there any workarounds for Spark 2.4.0 to be able to set a specific consumer group.id?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently (v2.4.0) it is not possible.

You can check following lines in Apache Spark project:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L81 - *generate group.id*

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L534 - *set it in properties, that are used to create `KafkaConsumer`*

**In master branch** you can find modification, that enable to setting *prefix* or particular *group.id*

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L83 - *generate group.id based on group prefix (`groupidprefix`)*

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L543 - *set previously generated groupId, if `kafka.group.id` wasn't passed in properties*

Comment: Thanks for the response, any idea on how I would go about implementing those modified classes? Is building a jar out of the package and adding that jar with spark-submit enough?

Comment: @PanagiotisFytas, you can check code in master branch of apache spark. I think it is enough to remove following line (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.0/external/kafka-0-10-sql/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/kafka010/KafkaSourceProvider.scala#L534)  and build and add jar to spark-submit and pass `kafka.group.id` property via `option`

Comment: I made this work by adding some commits from the master branch to the 2.4.0 branch. You can check my fork https://github.com/PanagiotisFytas/spark. You build the fat jar with the custom connector by calling [external/kafka-0-10-sql/mvn -DskipTests package]. I am not sure how safe that method is as I have not yet fully tested it.

Comment: @PanagiotisFytas, I would be very careful with it. For sure it is not recommended approach in the production . However it is only modification of kafka streaming part.

Answer (score 7):

#### Since Spark 3.0.0

According to the [Structured Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) you can provide the ConsumerGroup as an option `kafka.group.id`:

```scala
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .option("kafka.group.id", "myConsumerGroup")
  .load()
```

However, Spark will not commit any offsets back so the offsets of your ConsumerGroups will not be stored in Kafka's internal topic *__consumer_offsets* but rather in Spark's checkpoint files.

Being able to set the `group.id` is meant to deal with Kafka's latest feature [Authorization using Role-Based Access Control](https://docs.confluent.io/current/security/rbac/index.html) for which your ConsumerGroup usually needs to follow naming conventions.

A full example of a Spark 3.x application setting `kafka.group.id` is discussed and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64003405/how-to-use-kafka-group-id-in-spark-3-0-to-avoid-always-start-the-offset-for-late/64003569#64003569).

Answer (score 1):

[Structured Streaming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations) seems to be quite explicit about it:

> Note that the following Kafka params **cannot be set** and the Kafka
>   source or sink will throw an exception:
>
> *group.id*: Kafka source will create a unique group id for each query
>   automatically.
>
> *auto.offset.reset*: Set the source option
>   startingOffsets to specify where to start instead.

Comment: I know. At the time, I asked for workarounds, which are possible. I managed to make it work with the solution suggested.

Comment: @PanagiotisFytas Can you show the code (as a separate answer) to help us understand it better? That'd be super helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Now with spark3.0, you can specify group.id for kafka https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations

Comment: it has a warnig message that we should not use the group.id. if you turn on the log to be WARN level, you would see this.